# Getting a run time error while appending in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make a game in which "card" is a class for various cards in the game.
"player" as a class which contain a list of cards to contain card objects.
"game" as a class which contain a list of players to contain player objects.
So when I created a game object it went fine.
When player objects are appended in game object, it went fine.
Problem-But when cards object are appended in player object. all card objects are appended in all players

i am using PyCharm and Python3.6.2(v3.6.2:5fd33b5)

```
class game:
    players=[]

class player:
    cards=[]

class card:
    def __init__(self,number,suit,player):
        self.number=number
        self.suit=suit
        self.player=player

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g=game()
    for i in range(0,4):
        g.players.append(player())
    for i in range(0,52):
        g.players[i%4].cards.append(card(i%13,i/13,i%4))
```

Expected -Each player should contain 13 cards as of i know.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is how you define the `player` class; `cards` is defined as a *class* variable, meaning that each instance of `player` shares the same `cards` variable. Since each player should have different cards, `cards` should be an *instance* variable, as follows:

```
class player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards=[]
```

As an aside: it is generally better to give your classes initial-caps names, like `Game`, `Class` and `Player`.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this process:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.players = []

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

class Card:
    def __init__(self, number, suit, player):
        self.number = number
        self.suit = suit
        self.player = player

    def __str__(self):
        card_string = f'{self.suit}\'s {self.number} of player {self.player}'
        return card_string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = Game()
    for i in range(0, 4):
        g.players.append(Player())
    for i in range(0, 52):
        g.players[i % 4].cards.append(Card(int(i % 13), int(i / 13), int(i % 4)))
        print(Card(int(i % 13), int(i / 13), int(i % 4)))
```